# Using SimpleDateFormat in a for loop on a list of objects

Tags: java, android

My app crashes whenever I try to do this:

```
for (CalendarEvent event : this.ListofEvents){

                 String myDate = new String(event.getDate());
                    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
                    try {
                        theDate = format.parse(myDate);
                    } catch (ParseException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    System.out.println(theDate.getDate());
             }
```

If I just print event.getDate() as a test, it displays all the dates. But when I try to format each date I'm assuming it locks up the phone resources. It's a fairly large List with many entries.

Perhaps there's a better method of getting the day, month, and year without taking up all the resources.

Comment: does event.getDate() return an instance of java.util.Date ?  If so why are you trying to parse the date again? thats wierd.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do and what error is shown? Also move the format object to outside the loop as otherwise an new object is created on each loop which is very inefficient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why are you creating a DateFormat inside the loop?  You create it, use it, and then it goes out of scope for GC in the next iteration.

Move it outside the loop:

```
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
format.setLenient(false);               
for (CalendarEvent event : this.ListofEvents){
    // what does event.getDate() return?  A java.util.Date?  If yes, why are you doing this at all?
    String myDate = new String(event.getDate());
    try {
        theDate = format.parse(myDate);
        System.out.println(theDate.getDate());
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```